# Get a button from a gridLayout

Tags: java, swing, grid-layout

If I have elements inside my gridLayout, can I get the reference to that object, if yes, which function do I need to use? Is it good idea to perform some actions on the objects inside gridLayout? Or there is another better language idiom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cannot get references to items from a layout.  However, you can from the container that holds the button.  A better solution might be to hold a reference to the button at a higher level of scope in order to be able to access it later.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get stuff out of a `LayoutManager` unless it specifically supports it, and `GridLayout` doesn't.

If you are putting `Component`s into a `Container` then you probably have a reference to them anyway. Can't you pass this reference around?